# JAVA - insert into DB problem

Tags: java, database, odbc

I've got a problem where I'm inserting data into a database. It's returning that 1 row is being inserted, but when I actually check the database, nothing new has actually been inserted.

Here's my update function:

```
public int update(String sqlStatement) {
    int rows = 0;
    try {
        Statement st = this.conn.createStatement();
        rows = st.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
        this.conn.commit();
        st.close();
            } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("Got err doing update: " + err.getMessage());
    }   
    return rows;
}
```

And here's the function calling it via it's object:

```
            db = new Database();
            int rows = 0;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tblStudent (firstName, lastName, username, password, isAdmin) ";
         sql += String.format("VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d)", fName, lName, username, passwd, isAdmin);
            System.out.println("Trying " + sql);
            if((rows = db.update(sql)) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Could not create new user");
                throw new Exception();
            }
            System.out.println("Rows " + rows);
```

As I said, it's reporting that a single row is inserted into the DB, but nothing is actually there. The DB is a MS Access DB.

Any help appreciated.

G

Comment: First, use prepare statement not manual concatenation.

Comment: When you check the database outside of this application, has the applications connection been closed?

When you execute the SELECT query from your application with this connection, is the data there?

Comment: Before I do the insert, I do a select, checking to see if certain users are present in the DB. This select works fine and correctly gets data from the same table.

RE: using the prepare statement. I realise there are other ways of doing this, but I'd like to try and understand why this particular way isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fixed the problem.

Seems you have to close the connection. Even if isn't being reused.

I added the following function to the Database class:

```
    public void close() {
    try {
        this.conn.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("Error while closing connection: " + err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And then added the close to the other functions in a finally clause:

```
        try {
            db = new Database();
            int rows = 0;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tblStudent (firstName, lastName, username, password, isAdmin) ";
            sql += String.format("VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d)", fName, lName, username, passwd, isAdmin);
            System.out.println("Trying " + sql);
            if((rows = db.update(sql)) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Could not create new user");
                throw new Exception();
            }
            System.out.println("Rows " + rows);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println("Got err in registerUser: " + err.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
```

Makes me wonder why there's even the option to commit then, since it actually doesn't do a commit even though you've told it to commit.

Comment: Be aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do a simple test with a FistName having a single quote in it.

Comment: You'll want to make sure that whatever code is run in the db.update() method you're using is also closing any database resources that it's using.